# Login Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code below which validates a form. However, there is a bug in this code. When I enter something in username and leave the password blank, the form accepts it. It shouldn't be accepting it. Any idea why?

```
<html> 

     <head>  <link type = "text/css" type="text/javascript" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
              <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

       <script src="js/bootstrap.js"> </script>
     <script> 
       $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form');
            return false;
        }
    });
});</script>
     </head> 


 <body> 
<form class="well span6"> 

     <label>Username</label> 
     <input type="text" id="myName" class="span3 required" placeholder="Type your username here..." />  <br/> 

      <label>Password</label> 
     <input type="text" id="myPassword" class="span3 required" placeholder="Type your password here..." /> <br/> 

     <input type="submit" class ="btn btn-primary">
     <!-- <button class=""> Clear <br/></button><br/> -->

</form> 

</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried giving an id to the form?

Comment: @Adam is right, you must have a name attribute for each input.

Comment: Stranger, the `.validate()` plugin is working perfectly fine as demonstrated in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHytZ/).  Your problem is elsewhere in your code and I suggest you construct a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: That jsfiddle does not work for me (ff 17). It only works if you focus then unfocus on the password.

Comment: Yes, I see.  However, the OP is complaining that his form `passes` validation.  He still has a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Works much better with `name` attribute, but still working (not passing a invalid form):  http://jsfiddle.net/hHytZ/5/

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the OP's question. The form should never submit if name and password are empty. The issue the OP was having is that the form was submitting if the password was blank, which is wrong. Adding the `name` attribute makes the validation behave as expected (as per my answer).

Comment: I did not misunderstand anything... in _my browser_, the form does _not_ pass validation when the fields are left blank.  Maybe your solution is indeed the actual answer (for all browsers)... that will be for the OP to declare.

Comment: I'm sure now that Adam is correct and that how each browser handles the `placeholder` is what's causing the inconsistency when `name` is left out.  Regardless, the `name` attribute should not be left out.

Comment: Just to clarify all previous discussion.  This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZZEJ/) has both `name` and `placeholder` attributes removed.  In _Safari_, it's half-ass working, where it validates one field at a time, and will not allow a blank form to submit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this validation plugin like a 'name' attribute on the field.

I've added `name="myName` and `name="myPassword` on each input and it seems to work in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6CC9/1/)

```
<form class="well span6">    
     <label>Username</label> 
     <input name="myName" type="text" id="myName" class="span3 required" placeholder="Type your username here..." /><br/> 

      <label>Password</label> 
     <input name="myPassword" type="text" id="myPassword" class="span3 required" placeholder="Type your password here..." /><br/> 

     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to by adding the "name" attribute, to the password and username fields.

Comment: @Sparky See this my friend http://jsfiddle.net/hHytZ/3/, you remove the field "name" and you see the original error